# Angular Material - align mat-checkbox to the left

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

I am trying to align `<mat-checkbox>` to the left of its container. By default it is indented. I tried to set negative left margin, it works, but the highlight circle is cropped.

[image]

I wonder if there is a solution for this issue. Here is the code I have so far:

properties.dialog.html:

```
<div class="form-field" *ngIf="control.type == 'TextInput'">
    <div class="label">{{ control.label }}</div>
    <mat-form-field>
        <input type="text" matInput [formControlName]="control.propertyName">
    </mat-form-field>
</div>

<ng-container *ngIf="control.type == 'CheckboxInput'">
    <mat-checkbox [formControlName]="control.propertyName">{{ control.label }}</mat-checkbox>
</ng-container>
```

properties.dialog.scss:

```
mat-checkbox {
    margin-left: -11px;
}
```

Comment: Probably due to `overflow: hidden` on some ancestor element. Perhaps on the tab component you appear to be using there ...?

Comment: @CBroe Thank you. Indeed, the tab component is responsible for the cropping.

Answer (score 1):

The Material Tab component is responsible for the cropping. It can be solved by setting a few styles.

```
::ng-deep .mat-mdc-tab-body-wrapper {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
::ng-deep mat-tab-body {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
::ng-deep .mat-mdc-tab-body-content {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

[image]